# Why is Bonferroni considered a conservative multiple comparison tool?

Tags: statistical-significance, bayesian, bonferroni

Bonferroni correction seems to be known as a "conservative" way to determine. Why is it called conservative? Is it because it assumes independence among all tests? Sort like Naive Bayes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bonferroni correction is based on the fact that

$$
P(\cup_{j=1}^{k} A_j) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{k} P(A_j) 
$$

for events $\{ A_j \}_{j=1}^{k}$, which can be a poor upper bound when the events are not disjoint.  For multiple testing problems this is almost certainly the case.  So in controlling the family-wise error rate by way of this bound the true error rate (conditional on the overall null) will generally be smaller than the nominal rate, and so we say the correction is conservative.

Comment: Interseting! Thank you for the response and that nice equation. So - it assumes that the probability of making a Type I error for each of the tests is independent. In most comparison tests, they have a well-defined joint probability.

Comment: ^ Is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't assume independence (independence and mutual exclusivity are different, also), it just controls the worst case scenario.  Somewhat similar to a "minimax" approach.

Comment: But aren't the events `mutually inclusive`? I could test adding a new button to my website and testing a new layout - both could lead to positive responses. Hence, both of those events are good.

Comment: Mutually exclusive would mean you can't simultaneously reject more than one hypothesis when the overall null is true.  It doesn't make a lot of sense from a practical standpoint but it's a mathematical upper bound that always holds.

Comment: Is that probability equivalent to: 1 - P(None of the Tests Giving False Positive)

Comment: Hence P(Getting at Least 1 False Positive) = 1 - P(Alpha)^K where we do K tests

Comment: If the tests were independent it would be $P(\cup_j A_j) = 1 - P(\cap_j A_j^c) = 1 - (1 - \alpha^\star)^k$ where $\alpha^\star$ is the error rate for a single test.